# HtmlEditorConfig settings overridden by addButtonsTo...() in framework/admin/_config.php

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm customizing the HtmlEditor for a site, and trying to remove the "Insert Media" button from the TinyMCE editor using HtmlEditorConfig settings in mysite/_config.php. Other changes to the HtmlEditorConfig are working, but certain buttons can't be removed. I believe they're being overridden by these lines in the framework/admin/_config.php:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->addButtonsToLine(...);
```

I've tried several different options, individually and in various combinations:

Resetting the entire line:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setButtonsForLine(2, 'undo', 'redo', ...);
```

Removing the buttons:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->removeButtons('ssmedia', 'ssflash');
```

Disabling the media and advimagescale plugins:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->disablePlugins('media', 'advimagescale');
```

The HtmlEditor won't render in the CMS, if I include 'formatselect' in a ->setButtonsForLine() call. I believe this is being caused by the ->insertButtonsBefore('formatselect', 'stylesheet').

The separators for the 'tablecontrols' remain, though the buttons are removed, when the 'table' plugin is disabled, because 'tablecontrols' are added to line 3 in framework/adming_config.php.

Is there anyway to override the settings in mysite/_config.php or will I need to make changes to framework/admin/_config.php directly?

Comment: Putting `HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->removeButtons('ssmedia');` in `mysite/_config.php` works for me in Silverstripe 3.1.5.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Interesting. I'm also using 3.1.5, and it's definitely not working. Though all configurations work correctly when I edit framework/admin/_config.php. I also saw comments in the SS forum before posting that it's not working for others, but not sure the exact version they were using. Changes to the valid_elements array also only for me if I edit framework/admin/_config.php.